# Find the solution for a boundary value problem

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

Please, how can we find the solution of this second order boundary value problem
$$-(e^{-2x}u')'-\ln(x^2+2)u= 2 e^ {-2x} - x \ln(x^2+2),\,\, x\in ]0,1[, u(0)=0,u(1)=1?$$

Or more generally, What's the change of variable we can use to find the exact solution of the problem 
$$-(P(x)u')'+q(x)u=f(x),x\in ]0,1[, u(0)=0,u(1)=1$$
?

Help me please.

Comment: I think there is a little mistake. Check the signs in front of the exponential. Is it by any chance $$-(e^{-2x}u')-\ln(x^2+2)u=-e^ {-2x} - x \ln(x^2+2),\,\, x\in ]0,1[, u(0)=0,u(1)=1$$ instead?

Comment: Did you mean $-(e^{-2x}u')'$ by chance?

Comment: i change it in my post. Can you help me please to solve it. Tank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

$u_1(x)=x$ is a solution. You can find the second (linearly independent) solution by using reduction of order, that is, set $u_2(x)= xv$ and determine $v$.